# How to change element text if contains multiple specific child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wanting to manipulate the comment text to show no comment only if it contains the default comment. That default comment is being hidden but adding to a counter. So it's hidden I want the comments to show `No Comments`, even though the counter may be at 3. Hope this makes sense.

I currently have this jQuery

```
$("p:contains('Default Comment')").parent().hide();
```

Here is my code example of what I have:

```
<div id="parent">
   <h4>Comments</h4>
   <ul>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="parent">
  Comments
  <ul>
    <li>Custom Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
    <li>Custom Comment</li>
  </ul>
```

Here is what I want to have happen

```
<div id="parent">
 <h4>**No Comments**</h4>
  <ul>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="parent">Comments</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Custom Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;>Default Comment</li>
    <li>Custom Comment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have an additional closing div in your posted code. "parent" div closes after the comments text, but another closing tag exists after the ul close

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly should happen based on what?

Comment: Please be more specific on your **Q**, you have not even define what you want to do. Just 2 codes. For what purpose or using what no idea. How are you getting the value no idea?

Comment: You need to loop through each group and check if there are any visible `li` elements: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: What is logic? If all `li` that that are placed into a `.parent` have `display:none` style, then the `.parent` content should be replaced by _No Comments_, shouldn't it?

Comment: What is your definition of "multiple specific child"?

Answer (score 1):

HTML's text is actually wrapped inside an invisible `textNode`, which you can access using element's `childNodes` property.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
var commentsParent1 = document.querySelector("div.parent:nth-child(1)");

// Text node is the first child in this case
var textNode = commentsParent1.childNodes[0];

// Now we can modify it's text content
textNode.textContent = "**No Comments**";
```

---

**Edit**: after seeing further clarification about the problem.

To detect that comments section has "default comments only" and replace it's "label" accordingly, you have to loop through the contents of the list. To make it more readable, you can wrap this inside a function that operates on a single comments section:

```
function updateCommentsSection (commentsSection) {
    // Select all comments in the list
    var comments = commentsSection.querySelectorAll("ul li");

    // Convert nodesList to an instance of Array
    var commentsArray = [ ...comments ];

    // Detect non-default comments
    var hasNonDefaultComment = commentsArray.some(function (comment) {
        return comment.textContent !== "Default Comment";
    });

    if (hasNonDefaultComment) {
        // No need to change anything
        return;
    }

    // Default comments only, change the content of the parent
    var textNode = commentsSection.childNodes[0];

    textNode.textContent = "**No Comments**";
}

// Example call to the function, you can use another for-loop to iterate over all the comment sections
updateCommentsSection(document.querySelector("div.parent:nth-child(1)"));

// Example loop that iterates over all comment sections
[ ...document.querySelectorAll("div.parent") ].forEach(function (commentsSection) {
    updateCommentsSection(commentsSection);
}
```

Comment: That changes the text, but how can OP detect if there are any hidden comments in the related `ul`?

Comment: That's not his question.

Comment: Given the input/output it would appear that it is.

Comment: To me it's not so clear - the only difference between these two gists is the changed text in the first "comment section". He also has 3 "hidden" comments there, so I have no idea why did you assume this means these comments "are not there", so to say (they could be hidden and waiting for some user action). If OP wants to detect whether comments are present or not, he should have said that in the question itself.

Comment: Well it would make sense that if the comments are not visible then the title above them should show 'No comments'... Either way it would be better for the OP to confirm their requirements

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can loop through the `.parent` elements and check to find the number of visible `li` elements within it. If there are none you can change the text in the first node. Try this:

```js
$('.parent').each(function() {
  var comments = $(this).find('li:visible').length;
  $(this).contents()[0].textContent = comments ? 'Comments' : 'No Comments';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  Comments
  <ul>
    <li style="display:none;">Default Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;">Default Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;">Default Comment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Comments
  <ul>
    <li>Custom Comment</li>
    <li style="display:none;">Default Comment</li>
    <li>Custom Comment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is really really close! I had to make some edits because this isnt my "exact" code. How would i manipulate this if this is a ID and in an h4 tag?

Comment: $('h4').each(function() {
  var comments = $(this).find('li:visible').length;
  $(this).contents()[0].textContent = comments ? 'Comments' : 'No Comments';
});     this is what I have, but it changes all of them to No Comments

Comment: I am not sure but I think it may be catching a not visible comment in a post that has non-default comments. Edit: I changed one to all custom comments and it still shows no-comment